# Oracle SQL TRUNC command shows year as 0022 instead of 2022

Tags: sql

I have some basic SQL coding

```
select
job.job_number,
job.actual_comp_date,
TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE(job.actual_comp_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')),'DD/MM/YYYY') as Truncated_Date

from
job
```

What I am expecting to see is

`job number      actual_comp_date         truncated_date`

`1234            01/04/2022 23:23:23      01/04/2022`

`1234            01/04/2022 23:23:23      01/04/2022`

`3837            23/04/2022 13:23:23      23/04/2022`

Instead what I am seeing is the year changed to 0022 as below:

`job number      actual_comp_date         truncated_date`

`1234            01/04/2022 23:23:23      01/04/0022`

`1234            01/04/2022 23:23:23      01/04/0022`

`3837            23/04/2022 13:23:23      23/04/0022`

How do I change the code so that it shows the year correctly?  Basically I want to strip the time out of actual_comp_date.

Comment: Hello you can go to tools-preferences-database-NLS and here where is date format make-DD-MON-YYYY in this moment you have dd-mon-rrr

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the trunc function altogether. It likes to return a 2-digit year. You can try to alter your session before running a trunc command to avoid it; however, this can be simplified as:

```
  select 
    to_char(to_date('01/04/2022 23:23:23', 'DD/MM/YYYY  HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  from dual
```

Output: `01/04/2022`